# Android VOIP - Building an app for audio and video calls

Tags: android, sip, voip, sip-server

I have to develop a mobile app with audio and video functionality. I browsed the web, I found out I need a SIP server. An SIP server does it works like Apache for web apps?

I also found this :

```
public SipProfile mSipProfile = null;
...

SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
builder.setPassword(password);
mSipProfile = builder.build();
```

But then at which point in my project I should tell that username = xxxx and domain = yyyy? Actually I cannot see the flow clearly it is starting from where and ending where..

Do you guys have a tutorial that I can follow?

Comment: You can read more about this here https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android

Answer (score 5):

A SIP server is the main component of an IP PBX, and mainly deals with the setup of all SIP calls in the network. A SIP server is also referred to as a SIP Proxy or a Registrar. Although the SIP server is the most important part of the SIP based phone system, it only handles call setup and call tear down. It does not actually transmit or receive any audio. This is done by the media server in RTP.

There are some widely used free & open source SIP servers like Asterisk, FreeSWITCH & penSIPS etc.

You can check here for [list of SIP servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_software)

You need to create SIP account or user on SIP server. Client will register to that SIP server using that SIP account with username & password.

Domain is basically SIP server's DNS hostname or IP address.

After registration to SIP server, client can make & receive audio or video calls.

Checkout here for [SIP Demo app in android](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/SipDemo)

Comment: Thank you Priyank.

Comment: But then I wanted to know is it a question of using WebRTC or SIP? Are WebRTC and SIP two different technologies but addressing audio and video communications? Or do I need to register an account with an SIP server and use a framework like WebRTC for quality audio and video calls?